# fetching public ip from different accounts in single aws environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

In my present project i am coming across one issue. Need to provide all the public and private ip from various accounts in single aws environment.

Can anyone please help me to get that code(wrapper).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for writing your code for you - please post an attempt and we'll be glad to assist.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried it by using following : aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress[]" --output table >> c:\logs\sample.txt   ... it saves public ips in given text file.

Comment: so you can add the PrivateIpAdress to your query: `aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[].[PublicIPAddress,PrivateIpAddress]"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by different accounts in a single AWS environment...did you mean different VPCs in a single AWS environment? Either way, here is the page for the CLI command *describe-instances*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html

This should allow you to potentially view information for all your EC2 instances, including the public and private IPs. If the CLI command seems like it's what you are looking for, you can look into writing code that does the same command using the AWS SDK for whatever language you are using. I'm more than happy to provide advice and help debug any issues you come across, but the rest of it is up to you.

Comment: Hi Fapple,Thank you for the info.   Unfortunately, the task isn’t as easy as it may seems, since these Elastic IPs are spread across multiple AWS accounts.
 
The challenge is to write a script that utilizes AWS CLI commands to retrieve all of the current Elastic IP addresses in all AWS accounts, and save that output to a file      " aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress[]" --output table >> c:\logs\sample.txt " here is the command that displays public ip of working account. Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: It is not possible to get details from other accounts using credentials from an AWS account. You have to either assume role in all accounts, get credentials and run the EC2 describe command or use access keys from all accounts.

Comment: Ah I completely misunderstood the question. What sudo said is correct. The CLI command I mentioned will not work across different AWS accounts.

Comment: Hi Fapple, can you brief about what that mean of "assume role", can you please help me with the steps